# What are the errors of the coefficients of a quadratic regression?

Tags: regression, descriptive-statistics, regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression

I have performed a quadratic regression in order to determine 
$y = a\cdot x^2 + b \cdot x + c$ by following the steps depicted in the section 'Find by Hand' in http://www.statisticshowto.com/quadratic-regression/.

The determined graph fits my measured values but now, I don't know how to calculate the errors of the coefficients $a,b$ and $c$.

If I perform a linear regression, I would use the Gaussian law of error propagation to determine the errors of the coefficients.
From lecture notes.
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sigma_i^2} = \frac{1}{\Delta x_i^2 + \Delta y_i^2} \label{eq:linregsigma}
\end{align}
Let $b$ be the slope and $a$ be the intercept
\begin{align}
    a &= \frac{S_y \cdot S_{x^2}- S_{xy}\cdot S_x}{\Delta} \; \; \; \text{ with error } \sigma_{a}^2 = \frac{S_{x^2}}{\Delta}\label{eq:linregintercept}\\
    b & = \frac{S_{xy}\cdot S - S_y \cdot S_x}{\Delta} \; \; \; \text{ with error }  \sigma_{b}^2 = \frac{S}{\Delta}  \label{eq:linregslope}
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
    S & = \sum_{i} \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}\; , \; \;
    S_x = \sum_{i} \frac{x_i}{\sigma_i^2}\;, \; \;
    S_y = \sum_{i} \frac{y_i}{\sigma_i^2}\;, \; \;
    S_{x^2} = \sum_{i} \frac{x_i^2}{\sigma_i^2} \; , \; \;
    S_{xy} = \sum_{i} \frac{x_i y_i}{\sigma_i^2} \label{eq:linregSequation}\\
    \Delta & = S \cdot S_{x^2} - S_x \cdot S_x
\end{align}

But here, in a quadratic regression, I have to solve a 3x3 linear equation system to determine the coefficients... If I determine the errors analogously the terms get so big that my matlab crashes... Am I doing anything wrong? How do I calculate the errors then?

Thank you!

Comment: quadratic regression is just a special case of multiple regression, so they can be obtained in the usual way for multiple regression

Comment: If you were able to get the errors, you would be able to correct the coefficients and get their exact values. Maybe you are looking for their uncertainty ?

Comment: I've tried to obtain the errors analogously, but somehow I don't seem to be able to find them... Do you have any tips? I've added some text to my question.

Comment: @Pascal : I've added some text to the question, is my 'error' = your 'uncertainty'? My lecture notes only use the term error...

Comment: Here are some search keywords: [multiple regression coefficient confidence interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multiple+regression+coefficient+confidence+interval).  Or perhaps you will find the answers found at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+coefficient+significant+answers%3A1+t-test to be more to your liking.  BTW, if Matlab crashes that's highly unlikely to be due to large terms.